# How to extract the substring from the beginning to a character?

Tags: python, string, web-crawler

I want to use Python 3 regex to extract a substring of URL from the beginning to the character `?`.

**input:**
`url = 'https://www.reuters.com/article/us-health-coronavirus-mexico-city/mexico-city-to-begin-gradual-exit-from-lockdown-on-monday-idUSKBN23K00R?feedType=RSS&feedName=worldNews'`

**expected output:**
`'https://www.reuters.com/article/us-health-coronavirus-mexico-city/mexico-city-to-begin-gradual-exit-from-lockdown-on-monday-idUSKBN23K00R'`

I tried the following:

```py
import re
end = article_urls[0].find('?')
article_urls[0][:end]
```

Comment: Why do you want to use regex? Is `url.split("?")[0]` enough for your expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a simple `split`.

```py
beginning, end = url.split('?')
```